# Find exact value of trig function given u and v

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the exact value of the trigonometric function
$$\cos(u-v),$$
given that $\sin(u)=\frac{12}{13}$ and $\cos(v)=-\frac{4}{5}$ (both $u$ and $v$ are in quadrant II).

Comment: Use the angle sum formulas: $\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$, where $a=u$ and $b=-v$.

Comment: Which part of this gives you trouble? Can you use the angle difference formula $\cos(u-v)=\cos(u)\cos(v)+\sin(u)\sin(v)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos(u-v) = \cos(u)\cos(v) + \sin(u)\sin(v)$$

Using the fact that

$$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1,$$

we can see that $\cos(u) = \pm 5/13$ and $\sin(v) = \pm 3/5$.  Since the two angles are in quadrant 2 we can say that $\cos(u) = -5/13$ and $\sin(v) = +3/5$.

Then,

$$\cos(u-v) = -\frac{5}{13}\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right) + \frac{12}{13}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)=\frac{56}{65}.$$